# How to handle page Access after login in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am newbie in zend and i have one small application having few page like login,search,index,add,email etc

I have only two type of user like below

1. Guest which has access of only login and index.
2. LoginUser which has access of search,add,email etc.

Means user can loin and perform other operation  or view info.

I have read acl of zend but not understood how it implement correctly. I can do it like core php but i want use zend coding standard

Kindly help in this. I stuck in this since two days. Any best way??

Note: Here i dont have any db all data comes form the web services only

Comment: In zf2 you have modules like [ZfcUser](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser) and [ZfcRbac](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/zfc-rbac) that do the job for you

Comment: Here but i dont have any db i need to pass this login info in webservices

Comment: ok and what is exactly the problem with Acl? have you looked at [Rbac](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.permissions.rbac.examples.html), too?

Comment: well i need to login with vocher number after that i need to set the role that this is login user and the according to role i want to do filter of page